# tkgetOpenFile is not displayed topmost

Tags: r

`tkgetOpenFile()` brings up the open file dialog, passes the focus, but the dialog remains in the background (using RStudio, Windows) instead of being placed topmost.

What am I missing, resp. how can I make the window being displayed in front of RStudio?

```
library(tcltk)
tkgetOpenFile()
```

Apparently not an unknown Problem:
http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Bringing-tk-choose-files-to-front-td4657938.html